# Samba4 Joining existing windows domain

Tags: dns, active-directory, bind, samba

Good morning,
I'm testing samba4 as a domain controller, and attempting to join it to an existing domain.  The only other DC is Server 2008 R2 and the domain functional level is also 2008 R2.  I'm using Samba 4.0.0beta2 (that's what's in the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories).  I have followed numerous guides and tutorials, but I can't for the life of me seem to get DNS replication working.  Shares/sysvol replication works fine, AD users replicate fine, but DNS is playing hard to get.

First and foremost, the official documentation seems to suggest that samba will use it's internal DNS server if no option is specified during join.  I'm trying to use BIND9.8; the --dns-backend option during a domain join no longer exists, so part of me is wondering if the samba DNS server and BIND9 are fighting eachother.  Is there a way to specify which DNS server samba should use? I tried adding 'dns backend' to the smb.conf file, but samba4 does not recognize this.  Again, documentation is hard to come across.

Below is my named.conf (condensed into one file), and smb.conf.  Some of the lines written were just copied from various documents on the web

named.conf:

```
acl samba4 { 192.168.4.0/24; };
acl interfaces { 192.168.4.21; 127.0.0.1; };

options {
        listen-on { interfaces; };
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
        notify no;
        recursive-clients 1500;
        tcp-clients 200;
        minimal-responses yes;
        provide-ixfr yes;
        request-ixfr yes;
        dnssec-validation no;
        forwarders { 192.168.4.1; };
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        tkey-gssapi-keytab "/var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab";
        recursion yes;
};

logging {
        channel daemon_info {
                syslog daemon;
                severity debug;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-time no;
                };
        category lame-servers { null; };
        category default { daemon_info; };
};

view "samba" {
        match-clients { samba4; };
        allow-update { localhost; samba4; };
        allow-query { localhost; samba4; };
        include "/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf";
};
```

smb.conf:

```
[global]
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = INTAAVEX
        realm = intaavex.com
        netbios name = LOLDC
        passdb backend = samba4
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, smb
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver, winreg, srvs$


[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/intaavex.com/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[Public]
        path = /shares/public
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem a different way.  I started over fresh, compiled BIND9.9.2 with dlopen and gssapi myself, and compiled the newest version of samba4 myself (as opposed to using the apt repositories), which is version 4.0.1 stable.

After joining as a DC, Samba replicates everything that's on the other domain controller.

Replication of the ForestDnsZones and DomainDnsZones from Samba4 to Server 2008 R2 does not work.  It works the other way around, however.  Everything else is replicated.  It looks like this is as good as I'm probably going to get it; even the latest stable version of Samba (4.0.1) still admits that replicating these partitions is not reliable.